# Drawing UITableViewCells for fast scrolling, but what about links?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I read [this](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/02/simple-strategies-for-smooth-animation.html) great article from Twitter about fast scrolling and how to draw cells. I have implemented this fine, but now the hard part - the links in the tweet. Is there any way to use this approach and draw links in the cell as well? I know this is possible using a number of different label extensions, but the article specifically mentions not using UILabels and UIImageViews. If I have to use UILabels to achieve this that's fine. I just want to be sure this is the only way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because detection of touch events is done in UIViews, one method might be to override the UITapGestureRecognizer on the UITableViewCell, and in the action it fires upon a touch, check to see if the tap is within the bounds of your link that was drawn. If it was, handle it accordingly, if not, handle it as a cell selection.

If you don't need cell selection, you could always have selection of a table cell perform the action you want for the link as well.

Comment: That sounds like something I will give a shot. There is no way to format these strings to look like links either?

Comment: I would use [NSString's drawing methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) (namely, 'drawInRect:withAttributes:') to format it how you like (ex: blue with an underline). Should do the trick.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the UITableView implements the UITapGestureRecognizer or the UITableViewCells do, so you might  experiment with trying it both ways (adding a new tap recognizer or overriding a default one). But finding the cell under the tap and the relative coordinates of that tap shouldn't be too difficult either way.